# Reference request: networks of morphisms where each morphism goes from a product to a product

Tags: category-theory

I am studying networks of morphisms where each morphism goes from a product to a product.

Does anyone know if there is literature or references on this?

In particular I study the following structure: a directed bipartite graph, with vertice classes 'variables', 'morphisms', where 'variables' are objects, the 'morphisms' are morphisms. As edges we have projections. Such that for each morphism f in 'morphisms' we have that the projections in In(f) make the domain of f into a product. And the projections in Out(f) make the codomain of f into a product.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I tried to explain the structures

Comment: You did not explain it enough.  Please do!